# one-to-one mapping hibernate using foreign key association

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate

am new to Hibernate learning entity mapping using hibernate framework via instead of annotation am using XML for mapping the entities

Here I have two classes Employee and Address [Address is the target class and Employee is the source class i.e is Employee table will have the foreign key column refers to Address table primary key]

```
class Employee{
String name;
int id;
Address addr;
//getter and setter methods
}

class Address{
String state;
String city
}
```

mapping.hbm.xml file:-

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Employee" table="emp">
<id name="id" column="id">
<generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
<property name="name" column="emp_name"/>
<one-to-one name="addr" class="Address" foreign-key="addr_id" cascade="all"/>
</class>

<!--mapping for Address Entity-->
<class name="Address" table="address>
<property name="city"/>
<property name"state"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Note:-
am using MySQL in table level I did not add a foreign key constraint to the employee table

And My Question while am try to save employee entity addr_id value is not stored in employee table how to resolve this issue.IN web most of the things are using annotations or shared a primary key.How to solve this issue kindly help me

Comment: How exactly are you trying to save?

Comment: your address has not PK.

Comment: Below is a link to xml based mapping spring and hibernate  example https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-xml-example/

Comment: Also check your logs or eclipse( or whatever you are using) console for full stack trace and post it

Comment: @fg78nc am mentioning the pesudo code for storing the entity:- creating employee and address entity and setting the property of corresponding fields Session session=sessionFactory.openSession(); session.save(emp); session.getTransaction().commit();

Answer (score 0):

Change your mapping. You need to fully qualify class name and indicate join column, which is PK of Employee, column `id`.

Employee

```
<class name="Employee" table="emp">
<id name="id" column="id">
<generator class="assigned"/>
```

Address entity have to refer to the PK of Employee, which is `id` in your case :

```
 <one-to-one name="addr" class="my.package.Employee"
                   unique="true" not-null="true" cascade="all"/>
```

Comment: yes i tried it but one-to-one tag does not have column attribute XML Parsing Exception has been occured

Comment: Updated, please try